# How to format the printing of elements in a list (java)?

Tags: java, arraylist, printing, printf

I want to print the elements of a list so it looks like:

1. element 1
2. element 2

...

nth. element n

How could I do that using System.out.printf or System.out.println?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int n=0; n<list.size(); n++)
   System.out.printf("%d.  %s %n", n+1, list.get(n));
```

or

```
int n = 0;
for (SomeType el : list) 
     System.out.printf("%d.  %s %n", ++n, el);
```

In both cases, the approach is to process the list "one element at a time", and then construct the output line for that element.  i.e., don't think about "printing the list", think about printing an element from the list.

Then, for each line, you need to know (1) the number of the element, (2) the value of the element.  The two approaches show the different ways you can iterate through the list -- by counting, or using a "for-each" iterator.  In the second case you need to manage the counting separately from the iteration.

I assume you can read about printf formatting, that I don't need to explain that part.

If the list is an ArrayList I'd expect the two to be roughly identical in performance. For a LinkedList, the first one is a little less efficient, and you'll notice if you have very large lists.  But the first one is a little simpler to write.

---

Test case coded and run:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class P {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
    l.add("fee"); l.add("foe"); l.add("fie");
    int n = 0;
    for (String el : l)
       System.out.printf("%d. %s %n", ++n, el);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
1. fee  
2. foe  
3. fie
```

Comment: this works great thank you! would you mind explaining to me how it works or giving me a resource as to how it works?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: `System.out.printf("%d.  %s %n", ++n, el);` - did you test this?

Comment: Then I hadn't. Now I have (added to answer).  But it's a pattern I've used many times, it scarcely needed testing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use println as following:-

```
 for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println((i+1) +" " +list.get(i));
  }
```